# Simple SQL that I am stuck on

Tags: sql

What percent of customers are reward members?

```
ID                 Reward Member
1                       y
2                       y
3                       n
4                       y
5                       n
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Count how many are members, divide by total number of customers and multiply by 100.

```
SELECT sum(case when RewardMember = 'y' then 1 else 0 end)*100.0/count(*) as percentage
FROM Customers
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `COUNT()`:

```
select
  1.0 *
  count(case when reward_member = 'y' then 1 else 0 end)
  / count(*) 
from t
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use conditional aggregation:

```
select avg( case when rewardmember = 'y' then 1.0 else 0 end) as ratio
from t;
```

Some databases allow shorter syntax, such as:

```
select avg( rewardmember = 'y' )
from t;
```

or:

```
select avg( (rewardmember = 'y')::int )
from t;
```