# SQL on Percent of Total

Tags: sql, group-by

What percent of customers are reward members? I am trying to put this in a subquery format to report the total amount of reward members from a table

```
ID                 Reward Member
1                       y
2                       y
3                       n
4                       y
5                       n
```

Comment: You have already asked this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61510559/simple-sql-that-i-am-stuck-on

Comment: Why ask the exact same question? You already received several 100% working solutions on the other question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation and `avg()`:

```
select avg(case when reward_member = 'y' then 1.0 else 0 end) reward_ratio
from mytable
```

This gives you a `0` to `1` numeric value that represents the ratio of reward members across the table. You can multiply that by 100 to get a percentage.

Comment: I need it in a subquery format

Comment: @sqlnoob: it is unclear what you mean by *subquery format*. You should make the effort to explain that better, and show the result that you expect, as tabular text. You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61513043/edit) for that, or [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).